# Using two core data models, one persistent store coordinator, and multiple persistent stores?

Tags: objective-c, database, core-data

I was wondering how the code for this image would look

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Art/advanced_persistence_stack.gif

I've tried to do it but I ended up saving both core data models to one sqlite database. How could you do as it is in the picture?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should your question title be "two persistent stores" then? Because at the moment it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Also, please show what it is you've currently tried.

Comment: I want one persistent store coordinator and two persistent store objects

Comment: I've got two data models that merge to one which I use to initialise the coordinator, it works but the two models are saved as a single database, I was wondering if it could be used to create two databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You direct specific entities to a persistent store using the configuration part of your data model (that bit at the bottom that everyone ignores). Add two new configurations, one for each persistent store, then add the relevant entities to each one.

Then, when adding persistent stores during the setup of your core data stack, use `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`, with the name of your configuration in the `configuration` parameter.

The coordinator will then save entities to the appropriate store for you.